# Using numpy roll in Keras

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to make a custom regularizer in Keras and I need to be able to roll the coefficient array.

I know this may be impossible however any mechanism that can replicate this roll function would be extremely appreciated.

```

```
def __call__(self, x):
    regularization = 0.

    # Add components if they are given
    if self.l1:
        # \lambda ||x||
        regularization += self.l1 * K.sum(K.abs(x))
    if self.fuse:
        # \lambda \sum{ |x - x_+1| }
        regularization += self.fuse * K.sum(K.abs(x - np.roll(x, 1)))
    if self.abs_fuse:
        # \lambda \sum{ ||x| - |x_+1|| }
        regularization += self.abs_fuse * K.sum(K.abs(K.abs(x) - K.abs(np.roll(x, 1))))
```

```

Comment: What's the dimension of `x`? If `x` is a matrix then it's probably a bit weird. Calling `np.roll` on a weight matrix will first flatten the matrix, shift the element linearly, and finally reshape it back to a matrix. Is this behavior exactly what you want, or is it `np.roll(x, 1, axis=1)`?

Comment: the dimensionality of x is always (m, 1) . And I know from testing it on a toy example with numpy that roll is the behaviour I'm looking for

Comment: @Yu-Yang EDIT: `np.roll(x, 1, axis=1)` gives the same result as `np.roll(x, 1)` in this example but `axis=1` is more explicit.

Comment: I've posted a possible way to implement it, please see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `x` is of shape `(m, 1)`, a possible solution is to use `tile`:

```
def roll_reg(x):
    length = K.int_shape(x)[0]
    x_tile = K.tile(x, [2, 1])
    x_roll = x_tile[length - 1:-1]
    return K.sum(K.abs(x - x_roll))
```

It will result in some extra memory usage, but if `x` is a 1-dim vector, I guess the overhead won't be too bad.